# Ember-data with ajax call on a different server

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I'm quite new with Ember and I wanted to use Ember-Data as mush as I could but I'm fetching data from an other server.

So far, I didn't use ember-data for anything unless for the user login information... I wanted to know if it was smart to fetch the information from the server and to save it in Ember-Data to use it straight after.

Server data ==> Ember-Data ==> Display information on the app

And when I wanted to modify some information this goes like that :

Information updated ==> Ember-Data ==> Server

Is this could be a good way to use ember-data with an ajax call ? Or is there is any other proper method to do it ?

I must say that for every call I've got a lot of data back, and I don't know if I should create every field in my model or if ember-data is doing it itself.

Thanks for your help.

[edit] After I  reading your answer I tried to figure it out how to do it but its hard..

For example  I have to send a GET request to my server like this :

`store.find('enquiries');` This should return me all of my enquiries on my server.

But how the store build for it ?

Should I do just this in my store.js ?

```
App.store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: '-active-model'
})

App.Enquiries = DS.Model.extend({

});
```

In my Model I've put this :

```
DS.ActiveModelAdapter.reopen({
    host: 'http://localhost/'
});
```

I've tried to read the doc, but there is not much explanation about it :/

Comment: Take a look at the Models guide in Ember, http://emberjs.com/guides/models/. It should be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You can use ActiveModel

```
 DS.ActiveModelAdapter.reopen({
      host: 'http://api.your-api/v1'
    });
```

and in your store

```
  App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: '-active-model'
  });
```

**Option 2:**
Rest Adapter

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'http://api.your-api/v1'
});
```

That's it, now all your request are going to be redirected to your new "host"

Reference http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: For the option 1, this will generate the store model dynamically ? like if I receive this from my server {name: "toto", pass: "tata"} no need to create them in my model ? Because I need to do almost an ajax call for every page I visit, is that viable ? Like I have to send some GET to /enquiry or /session etc

Comment: I'm not sure if you don't need a model, in most of the cases ember will create a default object if needed. You should give it a try.

Comment: Okay, so now when ember-data is making a request, it add a 's' at the end of my location request ? It is possible to change that ?